# How to enable right click to inspect element on ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid

I am unable to right click like normal to inspect element on the ag-grid. How do I enable that (reenable it?)

Answer (score 1):

Holding down the Ctrl-Key and right clicking will show you your browsers context menu.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/context-menu/#default-context-menu

Comment: Doesn't work for me on my Macbook. Any other suggestion? Holding down CTRL + click on mac trackpad is how you normally do right click anyways.